# How to connect a sink to a external waveform port in REDHAWK?

Tags: redhawksdr

I'm trying to write a unit test for a REDHAWK waveform. I would like to use stream sources to input data and stream/message sinks to store the output. I have written unit tests for components this way, but wanted to create a test for a waveform as well. I found a solution for connecting a StreamSource to a waveform's port, but have not been able to determine how to connect a sink to a waveform port.

For a source and a component (where `self.comp` is the component), normally one can use the following to connect them:

```
src = StreamSource(streamId='strm1', format='short')
src.connect(providesComponent=self.comp,
            providesPortName='dataShort_in',
            connectionId='testConn')
```

For a source and a waveform (where `self.app` is the waveform), I was able to get the following to work:

```
src = StreamSource(streamId='strm1', format='short')
src.connect(providesComponent=CorbaObject(self.app.getPort('dataShort_in')),
            connectionId='testConn')
```

However, for a sink I would normally call `connect` on the component:

```
sink = StreamSink('short')
self.comp.connect(sink, usesPortName='dataShort_out')
```

I tried to use a similar approach as for the source case by getting the port from the waveform as below:

```
sink = StreamSink('short')
self.app.getPort('dataShort_out').connectPort(sink, 'outputConn')
```

However, this gives the error:

```
File "/usr/local/redhawk/core/lib/python/ossie/cf/Port_idl.py", line 86, in connectPort
  return self._obj.invoke("connectPort", _0_CF.Port._d_connectPort, args)
BAD_PARAM: CORBA.BAD_PARAM(omniORB.BAD_PARAM_WrongPythonType, CORBA.COMPLETED_NO, ["Expecting object reference, got <class 'bulkio.sandbox.streamsink.StreamSink'>", "Operation 'connectPort' parameter 0"])
```

I am not sure how I can get a CORBA obj ref for the sink to use here. Or is there another approach I can use here to connect the port to the sink?

I am using REDHAWK 2.2.2 on Centos 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have found a solution to my own question. I ended up creating a new class that manages port connections that works for both sinks and sources. I called it `ConnectionManager` (hopefully it won't be confused with the `ossie.utils.model.connection.ConnectionManager` class.

```
class ConnectionManager:
    def __init__(self):
        self.connections = list()

    def clear(self):
        del self.connections[:]

    def connect(self, usesPort, providesPort, id):
        usesPort.connectPort(providesPort, id)
        self.connections.append( (usesPort, id))

    def disconnectAll(self):
        for port, id in self.connections:
            port.disconnectPort(id)
        self.clear()
```

Here's an example using a `StreamSource` (`self.cm` is a `ConnectionManager`):

```
strm = sb.StreamSource(streamID='strm1', format='short')
self.cm.connect(strm.getPort('shortOut'),
                self.app.getPort('dataShort_in'),
                'connID')
```

And an example using a `StreamSink`:

```
sink = sb.StreamSink('short')
self.cm.connect(self.app.getPort('dataShort_out'),
                sink.getPort('shortIn'),
                'conn2ID')
```

My unit test `setUp` method has a call to `self.cm.clear()` and the `tearDown` method a call to `self.cm.disconnectAll()` to clean up the connections after each test.

The only thing I don't understand is the names of the ports for the sink and source classes. Using the `{format}{In|Out}` names work, but I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

The same process that you applied for connecting a component to a sink applies to an application, as long as the application is a sandbox object rather than a CORBA one:

```
dom = redhawk.attach()
app = dom.apps[0]
sink = sb.StreamSink('short')
app.connect(sink)
```

The next code shows the names of the ports. In this case, there is just one of type short.

```
from pprint import pprint
pprint(sink._providesPortDict)
```

The code below shows the syntax for using a CORBA reference instead of a sandbox object.

```
sink_port = sink.getPort('shortIn')
ref = app.ref
ref.getPort('dataShort_out').connectPort(sink_port, 'outputConn')
```

You can run a waveform in the sandbox. Note that the waveform's components need to run on the local host.

Use the `nodeBooter` shell command or `kickDomain` from the `redhawk` Python package to start a domain manager and a device manager.

Sample code to run a waveform in the sandbox:

```
import os
from ossie.utils import redhawk, sb

dom = redhawk.attach()
SDRROOT = os.getenv('SDRROOT')
waveform_dir = os.path.join(SDRROOT, 'dom', 'waveforms')
waveform_name = os.listdir(waveform_dir)[0]
app = dom.createApplication(waveform_name)
sink = sb.StreamSink()
app.connect(sink)
```

Comment: Can you run a waveform in the sandbox? I see the `loadSADFile` function that will load all the components of a waveform into the sandbox, but that's a little different than running the actual waveform in a domain I think. Plus this function doesn't return an app object. For my test, I wanted to test connecting to the external ports of the waveform. Is there another way to load a waveform into the sandbox I could use? (Also, I think you're missing a `getPort` in the last line of your example code above.)

Comment: I edited the answer as a response to your comment. Thanks for pointing out the missing `getPort`.